# "linear-gradient" not working in IE9 and Safari

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, safari

I try to apply a style to a button but this style displays well on Mozilla and Chrome then it is not the case for Safari and IE9.

Here is the css class:

```
#bt_D{
width:130px;
height:30px;
box-shadow:1px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
font-size:12px;
background-image:linear-gradient(60deg, rgb(231,110,49), rgb(231,171,49));
border:1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
border-radius:5px;
float:right;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

But when i inspect the button , i find in quoted of the property `linear-gradient` a yellow exclamation mark which indicates that this property is not recognized by the browser (safari or IE9)

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: I don't know about Safari, but in [IE9 gradients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#gradients) are not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Safari, you will have to put an additional, so-called "vendor-prefixed" version of the definition:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, rgb(231,110,49), rgb(231,171,49));
```

For IE9 (which has no support for CSS gradients) you must use an image as a fallback, either png/gif/jpg, or better SVG.

Here is one of many gradient generators that also creates the SVG you want:

> http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: i keeped for my css class : 

`background-image:linear-gradient(60deg, rgb(231,110,49), rgb(231,171,49));` but i added `background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, rgb(231,110,49), rgb(231,171,49));` for safari and i works good